# User not authenticating on successful login ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I created a application using ASP.NET with EF. I did the login function and when the user logged redirect to WelcomePage. The login was succeeded and redirect to the page but in the page I have the user authenticated.

I put this to see and its false

```
<p>@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>
```

I'm just having trouble understanding how to authenticate them. I try to clean cache but thats not the problem.

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string Con = ConUri();

        services.AddDbContext<SysContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(Con);
        });

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SysContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Login");
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        });

    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public object Login(String Username, String Password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Username).Result;

                if (user == null)
                    throw new Exception("Error 1");

                var result = _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user,
                        Password, lockoutOnFailure: false).Result;

                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                    throw new Exception("Error 2");

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                    throw new Exception("Error 3");

                var response = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Username, Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false).Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    var location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/WelcomePage");

                    Response.Cookies.Append("_UserId", user.Id.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("_User" + user.Id, string.Empty);
                    return new
                    {
                        Sucesso = true,
                        Url = location
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error ex");
                }
            }


            throw new Exception("Error 4");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new
            {
                Sucesso = false,
                Mensagem = ex.Message
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included app.UseAuthentication(); in your Startup.cs ?

Comment: Yes, app.UseAuthentication(); and app.UseAuthorization();

Answer (score 0):

You could check the EmailConfirmed Colum if it has a value in your database,if you did not set to send you a confirmed e-mail when you sign up,try to set as below to avoid varify the e-mail:

```
 services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                .......
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount=false ;
                ......                   
               
             })
```

Why you passed the username as an e-mail address?

```
var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Username).Result;
```

Comment: I try this and doesn't work. I set true on EmailConfirmed column but nothing.

Comment: I've updated my answer.please check it

Comment: my username = email. In the form I put email = username